# mysql, query with to where condation, if the one value = any thing

Tags: mysql, sql

table

```
id        name            value  
1         abc             12
2         def             13
4         mkg             14
5         pcr             10
```

**select * from table where name = 'abc' and value = 12**;--------------------- this will give me result of

```
1        abc       12
```

**SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'abc' AND value = 12 OR 1=1**

this will list me all the items, as it should only list the name='abc' and then search for the value of 12 or any thing if not 12 means blank it should fine anything.

```
    1         abc             12
    2         def             13
    4         mkg             14
    5         pcr             10
```

Here i want to get only the name='abc', but i have to run the tow conditions every time i do query. like (select * from table where name=x and value=x or 1=1)

should show the:

```
1    abc    12
```

the idia is user will give value for one of the column by input and the resut shoudl search acording to the user input.

```
query: (SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = x or 1=1 AND (value = x or 1=1)
```

so if the user doest query only for name ='abc' and value any

```
 select * from table where name = 'abc' OR 1=1 and (value = '' OR 1=1):
 select * from table where name = '' OR 1=1  and (value = 12 OR 1=1):
```

because the user will put one of them either the **name** or **value** so i have to put the **OR 1=1** in both of them.

```
<form>
<input type='text' name='name'>
<input type='text' name='value'>
<submit>
</form>
```

So NOW

1- if the user put value for both, it's ok with a simple Q= **where x=x and y=y**

2= if the user put value for one(name) Q= **WHERE name=x and value = '' OR 1=1;**

3- if the user put value for one(value)Q=**select * from table WHERE name = 'abc' and (value = '' OR 1=1):**

4-if the user put value for both(name,value) **Q=select * from table WHERE name='abc' AND value=12;**

now i want the query that can manage all so i did:

```
query = SELECT * FROM table where name = Get-INPUT OR 1=1 AND (value= Get-INPUT or 1=1)
```

but this is not working for me, as the condition (1=1) is true, it shows me all records.
question: how to manage my form, if user input for one condition other condition just user 1=1-true

regards

Comment: Are you just trying to get all rows where the name is 'abc'? If so then it is simply `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'abc'`

Comment: if you don't use brackets the system interpret the where clause in this mode: (name='abc' and Value=12) this give teh result abc 12 and then the querry evalute the or clause (1=1) which in your case is always true, so it give back all the other rows.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is wrong with the first result given? Why are you adding `OR 1=1` to the query?

Comment: first answer before update, as i have to condition in WHERE and user will give one value(for name or for value) so if one condition gets value the other will be null, as it's with AND it will not give result, so i set 1=1 means tue, now i set in both of them because user will input value for one, so as i set 1=1 in both means both conditions are true and result me all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use brackets in your query, to group your WHERE clause items logically.

```
WHERE name = 'abc' AND (value = 12 OR 1=1)
```

If you are trying to provide a query that accepts two variables, and searches based on those variables you're only slightly off in your logic.

**With both variables supplied**

Presuming we have two variables `@incoming_name` and `@incoming_value`:

```
SET @incoming_name = 'abc';
SET @incoming_value = 12;

SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE (@incoming_name = name OR @incoming_name IS NULL)
AND (@incoming_value = value OR @incoming_value IS NULL)
```

This will give you

```
1        abc       12
```

**With one variable supplied**

Then if the user supplies NULL for either of those values, it will skip over them in your search.

```
SET @incoming_name = 'abc';
SET @incoming_value = NULL;

SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE (@incoming_name = name OR @incoming_name IS NULL)
AND (@incoming_value = value OR @incoming_value IS NULL)
```

This still gives you the expected result

```
1        abc       12
```

**With no variables supplied**

If the user supplies neither of the variables to narrow down the search

```
SET @incoming_name = NULL;
SET @incoming_value = NULL;

SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE (@incoming_name = name OR @incoming_name IS NULL)
AND (@incoming_value = value OR @incoming_value IS NULL)
```

You will get all the results from the table

```
1         abc             12
2         def             13
4         mkg             14
5         pcr             10
```

**Using variables in your script**

Using this method you do not have to `SET` variable names in MySQL, that was just for demonstration purposes. You can put the value from your code/script in other languages as well. For example using PHP and PDO Prepared Statments

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE (:incoming_name = name OR :incoming_name IS NULL)
AND (:incoming_value = value OR :incoming_value IS NULL)
```

Then you can bind your user variables to `:incoming_name` and `:incoming_value` and it will search as you expect. If either are null it will skip over them, otherwise they'll be required in the search.

**Warning:** I have not tested this code, it's just to give you a rough idea on how it would work. It uses PHPs [PDO and prepared statements as documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 
    WHERE (:incoming_name1 = name OR :incoming_name2 IS NULL)
    AND (:incoming_value1 = value OR :incoming_value2 IS NULL)");
$stmt->bindParam(':incoming_name1', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':incoming_name2', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':incoming_value1', $value);
$stmt->bindParam(':incoming_value2', $value);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    var_dump($row);
  }
}
```

You need to bind each param in the query with a separate name, which is why when we want the same param twice we need to give it a separate name (`incoming_value1` and `incoming_value2`)

Comment: That's just `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'abc'`

Comment: the anser is correct, but here i have the query of(select * from table where name = x OR 1=1 and (value = x or 1=1)) because the user will give value for (name or value , either name or value) one of them or both of them.

Comment: I will update my answer to include an example of how you can perform that logic.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how you would filter the results based on various user inputs.

Comment: @SOomee I added a brief example of how you might achieve this using PHPs PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: This is what i get when i echo my $sql, (select * from table WHERE (name='abc' OR name IS NULL) AND (value= OR IS NULL),,,, but no result

Comment: You may have made a typo generating your `$sql` variable. It should read `select * from table WHERE (name='abc' OR name IS NULL) AND (value= OR value IS NULL)`. You are just missing the opening bracket after `WHERE`, and you don't need one before your select. Also you need to specify `OR value IS NULL` not just `OR IS NULL`.

Comment: it was mistak on comment not in here with me, sorry

Answer (score 0):

1=1 means `TRUE`. And `(? OR TRUE) = TRUE`.

That's why you will get all items if you have `OR 1=1` in your query. Then this would be enough:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'abc'
```