# MySQL Stored Procedure using parameters and query

Tags: mysql

I have a Stored Proc in MySQL that I want to use, in the WHERE clause of the SELECT Statement it will use a choice of 3 parameters

Example

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE (Postcode = @postcode
  OR StreetName = @streetname
  OR JobNumber = @jobnumber)
```

I understand that if there was only 1 paramater in the WHERE clause it would be CALL MyStoredProc('thevariable') to Execute the StoredProc, but with it having 3 in a WHERE OR clause how do I Execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple parameters to a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure(post_code VARCHAR(8), street_name VARCHAR(64), job_number INT)
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Postcode = post_code
OR StreetName = street_name
OR JobNUmber = job_number;

END
DELIMITER ;
```

To then run it, you call it like any other, but pass it all the required parameters

```
CALL test_procedure('ABC123', 'Charles St', 5134);
```

You can read more about them [here on the MySQL documentation website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html).

Comment: Thanks but if I only have 1 answer say the postcode how would it work?

Comment: You want the SP to give results on a `WHERE` clause where some of the parameters may be null? You can use the same method I discussed in an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623752/mysql-query-with-to-where-condation-if-the-one-value-any-thing/23623776#23623776), let me know if you have trouble translating it to your specific example.

Comment: I had a read of your link and this is what I made from it. Have I gone in the right way? `WHERE ((Postcode = post_code OR job_number IS NULL OR street_name IS NULL)
    OR (StreetName = street_name OR post_code IS NULL OR job_number IS NULL)
    OR (JobNumber = job_number OR post_code IS NULL OR street_name IS NULL));`

Comment: I added it into my PHP code and it works a treat :-) Thanks for the help!