# Do I have to use a second variable for a MySQL string query if I want to apply a parameter via MySqlConnector into that string query?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

Currently the only working way I found, would be to use a second variable:

```c#
string myProcedure = @"
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MyPersonProcedure;

CREATE PROCEDURE MyPersonProcedure
(
     
)



BEGIN

    Set @sqlQuery = NULL;

    -- some code...

    SET @personname_var = @personname;

    Set @sqlQuery = 'Select Name from PersonTest where Name = @personname_var';
    
    Prepare myQuery from @sqlQuery;
    Execute myQuery;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE myQuery;
    

END;
";


// ...

using (MySqlCommand procedureCommand = new MySqlCommand(myProcedure, conn))
            {

                procedureCommand.Parameters.Add("@personname", MySqlDbType.String);
                procedureCommand.Parameters["@personname"].Value = "Mike";


                procedureCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

But I would like to have something like this, which uses only one variable, but that doesn't work:

```c#
string myProcedure = @"
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MyPersonProcedure;

CREATE PROCEDURE MyPersonProcedure
(
     
)



BEGIN

    Set @sqlQuery = NULL;

    -- some code...

    Set @sqlQuery = 'Select Name from PersonTest where Name = @personname';
    
    Prepare myQuery from @sqlQuery;
    Execute myQuery;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE myQuery;
    

END;
";
```

Also the following did not work:

`Set @sqlQuery = 'Select Name from PersonTest where Name = ''@personname'' ';`lang-c#

Here is the full code for the working example, which uses two variables in MySQL:

```c#
 private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string personTable = @"
    drop temporary table if exists PersonTest;
    create temporary table PersonTest( Name VARCHAR(255), id int );
    
    Insert INTO PersonTest (name, id)
    VALUES
        ('Mike', 1),
        ('John', 2);

    Select * from PersonTest;

";



        string myProcedure = @"
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MyPersonProcedure;

CREATE PROCEDURE MyPersonProcedure
(
     
)



BEGIN

    Set @sqlQuery = NULL;

    -- some code...

    SET @personname_var = @personname;

    Set @sqlQuery = 'Select Name from PersonTest where Name = @personname_var';
    
    Prepare myQuery from @sqlQuery;
    Execute myQuery;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE myQuery;
    

END;
";

        string executeMyProcedure = @"
CALL MyPersonProcedure();
";


        string connStr = "Server=localhost;User ID=root;Password=superSecret;Database=DBIndependence;Persist Security Info= true;Charset=utf8;Allow User Variables=True";

        

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();


            // test table content:
            using (MySqlCommand tableCommand = new MySqlCommand(personTable, conn))
            {

                using (MySqlDataReader tableReader = tableCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    string output = "";
                    object[] values = new object[tableReader.FieldCount];

                    while (tableReader.Read())
                    {
                        tableReader.GetValues(values);

                        output += values[0] + "\n";
                    }

                }
            }


            // create procedure:
            using (MySqlCommand procedureCommand = new MySqlCommand(myProcedure, conn))
            {

                procedureCommand.Parameters.Add("@personname", MySqlDbType.String);
                procedureCommand.Parameters["@personname"].Value = "Mike";


                procedureCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }




            // get procedure output:
            using (MySqlCommand executeProcedureCommand = new MySqlCommand(executeMyProcedure, conn))
            {

                using (MySqlDataReader procedureReader = executeProcedureCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    string output = "";
                    object[] values = new object[procedureReader.FieldCount];

                    

                    while (procedureReader.Read())
                    {
                        procedureReader.GetValues(values);

                        output += values[0] + "\n";
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I also found out there is a way to use just Concat:

```mysql
Concat('Select Name from PersonTest where Name =   ', @personname)
```

or with using:

```mysql
Set @sqlQuery = 'Select Name from PersonTest where Name = ?';
Prepare myQuery from @sqlQuery;
Set @myparam = @personname;
Execute myQuery using @myparam;
```

But I think on very long or complex queries it might look confusing (hard to read).
That's why I'm asking for something like those mentioned examples that don't work.

---

The question was marked as duplicated with:
[MySQL Stored Procedure using parameters and query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23794818/22721830)
Which is in my opinion a different question (solution seems to be the other way around), so I will explain my issue in greater detail.

The reason I use prepared statements (those string queries) is, that I got a programm in C# in which SQL queries are created and concatenated by conditions (if ... else) and sometimes loops.

To make those direct in code queries database independent, I created a class with multiple readonly Dictionaries which contain for each databasesystem (MSSQL, MySQL, ...) an adjusted query (string). When the first query will be executed another dictioary will be created at runtime once which only includes the queries for the connected database based on that dictionaries in that class.

Those strings in the dictionary do not have variables like:

```C#
"Select name from PersonTest where name = "+ variableWithName
```

But are open to parameters like:

```C#
"Select name from PersonTest where name = @variableWithName"
```

Some of those queries are designed to get parameters (@personname for example) by the specific database-connector, e.g. MySqlConnector.

I assumed that executing strings would be the best way to handle those queries, which are concatenated by conditions or loops, because in a procedure I can for example use Concat() to concatenate queries by specific conditions here an example:

```mysql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ConditionTest;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE ConditionTest
(
     IN status int
)


BEGIN

    Set @sqlQuery = NULL;
    
    Set @sqlQueryAppended = ' order by name';

    IF status = 99 THEN
        SET @sqlQuery = 'SELECT Name from PersonTest ';
    ELSE
        SET @sqlQuery = 'SELECT Id from PersonTest ';
    END IF;
    
    Set @sqlQuery = Concat(@sqlQuery, @sqlQueryAppended);
    
    Prepare myQuery from @sqlQuery;
    Execute myQuery;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE myQuery;
    

END $$
```

So, back to the question:

I found out that in my opinion the cleanest way to write those queries would be to create another variable, ending with '_var', so I can use that one in the string query:

@personname is the parameter set by the MySqlConnector in C# code.

```mysql
-- ...

SET @personname_var = @personname;

Set @sqlQuery = 'Select Name from PersonTest where Name = @personname_var';

Prepare myQuery from @sqlQuery;
Execute myQuery;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE myQuery;
```

But it doesn't work when I just use @personname like:

```mysql
-- ...

Set @sqlQuery = 'Select Name from PersonTest where Name = @personname';

Prepare myQuery from @sqlQuery;
Execute myQuery;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE myQuery;
```

It seems @personname is not going to be set by the MySqlConnector, when it exists in a string query.

So, do I do something wrong or is there no way to use just **one** variable without to declare another variable like @personname_var?

Comment: There is no need to use prepared statements in mysql. Either use a perpared statement with parameters directly from C# or pass the name as parameter to the stored procedure, which can be used without prepared statement in the select.